# File.mkdir doesn't throw IOException but File.createNewFile does

Tags: java, io

The File class lets you create new directories and new files on a file system.

The methods to accomplish this are:

`public boolean createNewFile() throws IOException`

-and-
`public boolean mkdir()`

How does the operation of creating a new file potentially lead to an IOException being thrown but the operation of creating a new directory does not?

I'm trained as a Java developer to be very aware of operations that throw checked exceptions, so I would be expecting more consistency here unless there was a very good reason for the lack of consistency. Both methods return true if the operation succeeded.

Comment: did you check if the directory in which new file you are creating is already present or not? If not present, exception will occur.

Comment: Because that's the way they designed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's part of [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29):

> ```
> public boolean mkdir()
> ```
>
> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname.
>
> **Returns:**
>    `true` if and only if the directory was created; `false` otherwise

I would accept that the API could be improved in this respect.

Answer (score 2):

We can only guess, but *my* guess is that the main reason is that they learned.

[`createNewFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) was added in Java 1.2, which is several years after Java 1.0. And they have since learned that using return values are a bad way to communicate error conditions (they *knew* it before, but didn't apply it everywhere).

Note that when `createNewFile()` exists without an exception, then the requested file exists! The only distinction made by the return value is whether or not it existed before.

If it *fails* to create the file, then an exception is thrown.